# How to mask my local ip with an user friendly name?

Tags: ip, localhost, ip-address

I am developing a web application, I've made the project in my localhost, but the net users need to access to my project and I dont want to give them a non-friendly ip address, so I wanna user acces with a name for example

```
http://myproject/
```

Answer (score 3):

If this is on a local network you can [edit the hosts file](http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/edit-hosts-file-mac-os-x/) on your computer to "mask" the ip on the network. Of course you'll have to change the project to use the network ip instead of localhost.

Comment: This helped me assign a friendly name to my works Intranet, +1 since no one ever did.

Answer (score 0):

go to **MyComputer>Drive C>Windows>System32>Drivers>etc>**
**Open hosts file**

After opening the **“hosts” file** that will look as below. Here you can add your favourite domain name with the same IP address as I have added the ebaytemplate.com with the IP of 127.0.0.1.

now run you localhost and in browser type ebaytemplate.com you localhost will run :)